# Mixing solvents and other compounds - safety issues

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety, solvents, mixtures, explosives

I would like to know if it is safe to mix organic solvents together or organic solvents with some compounds listed below.

In a mixture with random ratios (greater than zero - all chemicals present) we have:

- Ethanol
- Methyl ethyl ketone (as denaturant for ethanol)
- Bitrex (aka Denatonium - as denaturant for ethanol)
- Isopropanol
- n-butanol (as denaturant for isopropanol)
- n-propanol (as denaturant for isopropanol)
- Ethyl acetate
- Acetic acid (in case that ethyl acetate hydrolyzes)
- Water (from ethanol and isopropanol)
- Acetone
- Methanol
- Naphtha (Hydrogenated)

In general, we have alcohols, ketones, denatonium, ester, organic acid, water, and a liquid hydrocarbon mixture (Naphtha).Ratios can be taken as equal for all chemicals except those used for denaturation.(I think ratios for denaturants  wouldn't matter in case they would react.)

Could some of these chemicals react together and produce any unstable or hazardous compound?

What conditions should be avoided? (Light,heat,etc.)

Any reaction (slow) that could happen with atmospheric oxygen? (opening and closing a bottle containing all these chemicals)

I don't know too much about organic chemistry, just asking to be sure this is safe.I want to test something that possibly involves mixing all the above chemicals and I don't know if they could probably react together.

Note: Question unrelated to waste disposal. I'm experimenting with a DIY electronics cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would suggest you read the material safety data sheets (MSDS) for each of those products to be sure of any incompatibility that may arise. They are available throughout the web or on distributor web sites like Sigma or Fisher.

For your list of waste disposal (as it seems to be) most of your products are alcohols or water so they can be mixed without issues.
The ethyl acetate will react with water to create ethanol and acetic acid and acids may be an issue if you have great quantities. So I would suggest to react and neutralise with $\ce{NaOH}$ prior disposal.
Same thing for acetic acid: you should neutralise prior disposal.

You can also request an evaluation of price from your chemical waste service contractor, which will give you the price of each disposal category with the incompatibility management included.

Comment: I read all MSDSs but I want to be sure about this.I have very basic knowledge of organic chemistry,I only know some reactions like hydrolysis.I don't know if something could react violently (even in case of hydrolysis) or there is a buildup of something dangerous over time.

The mixture is about to be used as a cleaner for electronics - I should have mentioned it. I also edited the original post (check the list).    
     
"Acids may be an issue if you have great quantities" is this about reactivity or disposal?

Comment: In presesnce of acetic acid could the following esters form?
 Isopropyl acetate,Butyl acetate,Propyl acetate,Methyl acetate ,(Ethyl acetate already in the list)

After searching MSDSs for esters above I didn't found anything related to corrosivity and reactivity except for Methyl acetate:"Reactive with oxidizing agents, acids, alkalis, moisture."

Does it has to do with acetic acid or just inorganic acids?

Regarding safety of each one,they seem to be ok but further from this I don't know if something could react with these new chemicals in the list - since they will probably be formed.